# Delete Mails in Mac Mail without Trash

Tags: mail.app, macos

How can I delete an email in Mac Mail instantly without moving it to the trash? I don't want to look at the spam crap twice :-)

**UPDATE**: I want to do this because I have some very old mails in my trash I don't want to delete at the moment (or decide what to do with). So I cannot delete my whole trash. But to avoid the trash becoming bigger and bigger I want to delete spam etc. without moving to trash...

Comment: I have the same issue. Due to a server error I have 25000 emails in a folder. I want to delete them instantly not move them all to the Trash folder.

Comment: Given your reason for not emptying Trash I would create a new folder and move the questionable messages from trash to it to allow you to review them

Answer (score 2, accepted):

Why look in the trash at all? Just set your Trash to automatically delete messages after a day. You can do that in the Accounts pane of preferences:

[image: Accounts pane]

Answer (score 13):

You can delete emails and bypass the trash using

<kbd>⌥ Option</kbd> + <kbd>⌫ Backspace</kbd>

(Successfully tested with OS X 10.9 (Mavericks). Could work with older versions, too.)

---

If you want to delete emails that are **already in trash** it is enough to hit <kbd>⌫ Backspace</kbd> to delete them permanently. If you are accustomed to also press the <kbd>⌘ Command</kbd>, like deleting a file in Finder, you can do so. But basically, backspace is enough.

Comment: still work on mojave

Answer (score 11):

All you have to do is any of the following:

- hold down the <kbd>Option</kbd> key, while clicking on the trash can on the top toolbar
- hold down the <kbd>Option</kbd> key, while clicking on 'delete' on the top menubar
- hold down the <kbd>Option</kbd> key, while right-clicking on the desired emails and scroll down to select 'delete'
- hold down the <kbd>Option</kbd> key, while pressing the <kbd>Delete</kbd> key on your keyboard.

Comment: Welcome to Ask Different! Answers are for directly answering the question being asked—use comments to reply to another user's answer.

Comment: I would have, George but, being a newbie, I'm not allowed to comment...yet.  Sorry...I'll learn.

Answer (score 0):

Delete the message: <kbd>⌘</kbd><kbd>⌫</kbd>

Then empty the trash: <kbd>⇧</kbd><kbd>⌘</kbd><kbd>⌫</kbd>

Comment: I think the questioner wants to avoid the trash completely.

Answer (score 0):

A very old tip (2006) from [MacWorld](http://hints.macworld.com/article.php?story=20060101172515184) suggests using <kbd>⌘ Command</kbd>+<kbd>X</kbd> to cut the messages and then just copying some text to wipe the clipboard. This seems to work, but Mail.app tries to copy the contents of those emails to memory - so probably not very useful for lots of mails with attachments.